# Disallow some websites from opening new tabs/windows

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari

In Safari how can I stop certain websites from being allowed to open new tabs and windows?

On some ad-heavy sites I click anywhere on the page and it spawns two or more new tabs trying to sell me some scam.

Can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

The best built-in defence for this is Safari Preferences → Security → Block pop-up windows. Other than this, you can use an adblock such as [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/el1t/uBlock-Safari).

Comment: The preference is already ticked.

Comment: I was using Wipr as my adblocker because it's so light and uses the content blocker to stop the ads from even being downloaded.

Comment: @theonlygusti I use AdBlock for the content blocker functionality too (network requests are still blocked even without content blocker support so ads aren't downloaded then anyway), but some more complex rules can't be expressed with content blocker rules